# How to return an array in function on jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I created a function in my react.I am getting data from another state and need to return an array with a function.Can i do this with .map and how ? If it is possible can you give me an example.

Comment: > "return an array with a function"

What do you mean by that?

Comment: i have a function like function() { .... } and this function needs to return an array like value:1 result:200,value: result:3000 ....

Comment: and what does the input data look like?

Comment: i didnt create for now but result = a * b can be an example

Comment: a * b? what is that? A Multiplication? ) Guess not... Can you clearly describe what do you need exactly?

Comment: yes that is a multiplication.for example i need a function which returning multiplication table.

Comment: `const input = [1,2,3,4,5]`    

`const processor = (number) => number * 10; // do your thing here`    

`const output = input.map(processor);`  

`console.log(output)`  
`// -->  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`